# Convert .corrWith pandas to pySpark

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, correlation

[image]

Hello guys. Could you help me with `.corrWith`? I can't find a solution to 'translate' pandas to spark

EDIT: I'm using two dataframes, so i need to establish a correlation between two dataframes

Code:

```py
pd.DataFrame({col:x.corrwith(y[col]) for col in y.columns})
```

This image below shows the perfect output but need that to be writed on spark

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.corr()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.corr.html) function.

Example:

```
df.corr(col('x'), col('y')).show()
```

For multiple columns just chain those functions together.

Comment: But that cannot be used with two dataframes, right? That's the point...